# How can i fetch data based on current date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Edit  Copy  Delete  119     anand   a   f   1957-05-08  5678    s   yyyy    anand_abc@gmail.com     2014-02-17 11:42:39     1
Edit  Copy  Delete  120     gangadhar   m   1952-02-04  495     c   xxxx    gang_v@yahoo.com        2014-02-17 12:02:16     3,4
Edit  Copy  Delete  124     ganesh  r   m   1991-09-04  9840    s   zzzz    gan_bab_raj@yahoo.com   2014-02-26 12:45:58     1
Edit  Copy  Delete  125     manesh  a   m   1991-02-05  9841    s   zzzzz   manesh.25@gmail.com     2014-02-26 12:45:5
```

I want to fetch the last two rows detail which has been inserted today. How can I fetch data based on current date.

Here is my query which is not giving desired output..

```
SELECT * 
  FROM stud_enq 
 WHERE date_time = GETDATE()
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM stud_enq order by date_time limit 2?

Comment: Thanx for the response. But limit does not work here. Because i want all the details which all are inserted on current date.

Comment: @user3354698 which database you are using??

Comment: the query seems OK but if there can be more than 2 entries in a given day (2 inserts) then you also need the time portion from the date column, have you tried Select Top 2 in the query ???

Comment: I m Using SQL server...

Comment: `date_time` datatype ?

Comment: @Usman Waheed: how can i use limit values when i dont know how many insertion happens on a particular day...

Comment: @Alexander: current time stamp.

Comment: Use `trim` function. If you don't, date_time never equals getdate()

Comment: thats what I am trying to indicate, the question says the query should return 2 rows inserted today, so the query must be able to filter through many entries that are inserted today, check the answers below

Comment: @Usman Waheed: I am really sorry about that. I want to fetch all data inserted on that date. Sorry for the mistake i have done in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for the fact that your `date_time` column *has* a time component, as does `GETDATE()`. Assuming SQL Server 2008 or later:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM stud_enq 
 WHERE date_time >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) and
       date_time < CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day,1,GETDATE()))
```

Selects all values which have todays date.

For older SQL Server, you can use:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM stud_enq 
 WHERE date_time >= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0) and
       date_time < DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),1)
```

Where the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` are just a trick for removing the time component.

Comment: This worked fine. Thank you so much. can you explain the query for mysql too??

Comment: @user3354698 - I'm not so good with mysql and unfortunately, date/time handling and functions vary quite a bit between database systems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
SELECT top 2 * 
  FROM stud_enq 
 WHERE convert(varchar(20),date_time,101) = convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),101)
order by date_time desc
```

Comment: Whilst that *is* a way to remove the time component, it also completely rules out any use of any indexes on the `date_time` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM stud_enq WHERE date_time = GETDATE() ORDER BY date_time DESC
```

Comment: who had down my answer? what is the mistake

Comment: I haven't, but from my reading of the question, the requirement to return 2 rows is based on there being two rows for today. If there had been 3 rows inserted today in the sample data, I believe that they would want 3 rows in the result. Also `date_time = GETDATE()` will only match if the date *and* time in `date_time` exactly match the date *and* time that `GETDATE()` returns.

Comment: I.e. their first comment in response to someone's suggestion was "limit does not work here. Because i want all the details which all are inserted on current date"

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT * 
      FROM stud_enq 
     WHERE date_time >= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0) and
           date_time < DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),1)
```

This will cover that full day without worrying about the time part

Comment: Whilst this will return you 24 hours worth of data, it returns you the data from (if run now) 07:50 UTC today until 07:50 UTC tomorrow. I presume the OP wants from Midnight at the start of today until the following midnight.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ok sir, edited using the DATEDIFF part